# .Net WebRequest.Create Decoding encoded URI

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-3.5

I am writing some rest calls to the LinkedIn API using web request and have hit an encoding issue.The LinkedIn API takes requires an encoded URI as one of the parameters on the lookup i am trying to run.

We are calling the api through .Net's WebRequest.Create; and when we pass in the URI it decodes it and as a result we can't get the data from the call. Im trying to open a URI like this

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2FProfileName
```

Is there a mechanism in the webrequest class to stop it decoding the passed in URI; or a work around for this?

Comment: When you pass that URI to `WebRequest.Create`, what is the result? That is, when you make a request, what does `WebRequest` send to the server? Also, are you calling `WebRequest.Create(string)`, or `WebRequest.Create(uri)`?

Comment: When the webrequest.create is called my URL transforms from the encoded form above to the non encoded form; and Linked in API fails as it requires encoded query string data. Appear to have a work around by encoding the URL 3 times but its inelegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain that this will work, but it shows some promise.

```
static readonly string UrlString =
  "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2FProfileName";


Uri myUri = new Uri(Uri.EscapeUriString(UrlString));
Console.WriteLine(myUri.ToString());  // this is only to show the string for debugging

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUri);
```

The output from `Console.WriteLine` there has the same format as the string you want. If you pass that Uri to `WebRequest.Create`, it may very well do what you want.

Comment: I have ended up triple encoding my url to stop the built in function from decoding it; doing it twice wasn't enough (it was already encoded as i passed the URL in) ... MS need to add in a method that doesn't do this...